# SharePoint site is showing old SSL certificate

Tags: 2010, ssl, certificate

I installed new cerificate on my SharePoint server as old one was getting expired in next month and updated bindings in iis to use newly installed certifite.But when i browse site with the URL it is still getting accessed by old certificate.When i tired to browse site locally it is using new installed certificate.
Please help me get newly installed certificate oprational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caching related. Clear the cache in your browser, or press CTRL+F5 to refresh it for that one page. If that doesn't help, do you have any proxies or other network devices that might be caching?

HTH

Comment: Thanks.We had proxy from where it was referring old certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question as I was having the same issue on a SP 2013 farm. I was quite certain that it was not caching in any proxy server as in the accepted answer for the question. I wanted to leave my solution as it may be helpful to others.

1. We had replaced the cert in the certificate store and modified the settings in IIS manager for all the sites.
2. We reset IIS and it still had the old certificates. I cleared my browser cache and even installed a new browser to test and I still received the old certificate.
3. We rebooted the server and it did not fix the problem.
4. I then deleted all the certificates (including the old one which I had not yet done) and reset IIS: still no change.
5. After number 4, I rebooted the server and it finally picked up the new certificate.

I manage and develop a lot of IIS sites and had no such problem on any of those. I hope this might be helpful to someone else in a similar situation. Just delete the old cert and take an outage for a reboot as soon as you are able. Certainly not the way this should be done...